# When I use `pip3 install --upgrade pip ` get error

Tags: python, django

I want to upgrade the pip:

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

But I get the bellow error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645) - skipping
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bellow method to upgrade pip:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this in docker by any chance? 
I sometimes have to restart the docker service on Mac when I get these kind of networking issues.

I did a check and everything looks fine at: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pypi.python.org

Is your time set properly on your machine? These kind of errors can occur if the system time is out of sync.